# can I use wine, is there a wine for mac, or similar

Tags: wine, mac

I installed Ubuntu on an iBook G4, and was wondering what I could run, but was wondering what all my `inxi` is telling me

```
william@william-laptop:~$ inxi -Fx
System:    Host: william-laptop Kernel: 3.2.0-123-powerpc-smp ppc (32 bit gcc: 4.6.3)
           Desktop: Unity 5.20.0 (Gtk 3.4.2-0ubuntu0.9)
           Distro: Ubuntu precise (12.04.5 LTS)
Machine:   No /sys/class/dmi; using dmidecode: dmidecode is not installed.
CPU:       Single core 7447A altivec supported (-UP-) cache: N/A
           flags: (-) bmips:  speed/max: 1199.999000MHz/1200 MHz
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RV280/M9+ [Mobility Radeon 9200 AGP]
           bus-ID: 00:10.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.11.3 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev)
           Resolution: 1024x768@60.0hz
           GLX Renderer: Rasterizer
           GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.4 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card PowerMac Snapper driver: PMac Snapper Sound: ALSA v: 1.0.24
Network:   Card-1: Broadcom BCM4306 802.11b/g Wireless LAN Controller
           driver: b43-pci-bridge bus-ID: 0001:10:12.0
           IF: N/A state: N/A mac: N/A
           Card-2: Apple UniNorth 2 GMAC (Sun GEM)
           driver: gem bus-ID: 0002:20:0f.0
           IF: N/A state: N/A speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 60.0GB (7.3% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: FUJITSU_MHT2060A size: 60.0GB temp: 46C
Partition: ID-1: / size: 54G used: 2.8G (6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda3
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 1.52GB used: 0.09GB (6%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda4
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   None detected - is lm-sensors installed and configured?
Info:      Processes: 141 Uptime: 21 min Memory: 302.8/494.9MB
           Init: Upstart runlevel: 2 Gcc sys: 4.6.3
           Client: Shell (bash 4.2.251) inxi: 2.3.8
```

Comment: Your question as it is makes no sense. WINE is a compatibility layer that allows *some* Windows software to be installed and run in Linux. It isn't related with the hardware although it may limit what emulated software can run. You need to be specific in your question.

Answer (score 5):

Wine requires a computer that has an x86 processor, like all Intel-based Macs have. You can't run Wine on an Apple iBook G4. PowerPC processors like your Apple iBook G4 has are incompatible with code compiled for x86 (Intel and AMD) processors.

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: and adding to this answer, only a virtual machine you can use

Comment: @fkraiem I can't give you a citation because there isn't one. The closest to a citation that I found for this is: https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ